# transfer contacts from sd card to computer via USB

Tags: data-transfer

Is it possible to transfer my contacts from a TMobile Concord Android sd card to my PC?  I have a USB cord.  I know the way to transfer it to Google, but this is my old phone with no service or connection.  I also have an Alcatel One Touch Fierce 2 that has some of my updated contacts on a SIM card (SIM won't stay in place because the metal piece that holds it broke off)  Again, no internet connection.  My new phone is an Iphone5c and I need to get those in there somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to do, and probably explained in some other answers here already:

1. Open the *Contacts* app
2. Hit the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button/key, and chose "Export/Import"
3. Select "Export to SD card" (creates a file named something like `0001.vcf` in the root of your SD card)
4. Either shutdown your phone and connect the SD card to your computer with a card reader, or connect the phone via USB (storage should show up there then)
5. copy the `0001.vcf` file to your computer

`*.vcf` is a file in [VCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) format and can be read by many applications. So you can import it into the software of your choice (or transfer it to your new device to be imported there) and check whether all contacts came along. In case the SIM contacts are missing, you might need to first copy them into your device's own contacts.